# BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, uiimage

I got this error when trying to open a UIImage from contents that I downloaded from a server.

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: <URL_here>)
// BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory
```

I was incredibly confused because the file existed and it was not a directory as the error suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this error can happen when your data is corrupted. The error is worst than non-descriptive. It is misleading.